# how do I find the mean value of one variable for every 5th percentile of another variable

Tags: r, mean, percentile

I want to find the mean of one numeric variable for each percentile of another numeric variable. To essentially replicate this graph (Marian et al(2012) but for my own data:

[*Figure 6. Average orthographic neighborhood size as a function of word frequency.
Frequency bins are evenly spaced divisions of words in 5% increments. Bin one represents the average orthographic neighborhood size of the top 5% most frequent words in the language, bin twenty represents the average orthographic neighborhood size of the 5% least frequent words.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi9wv.png)

I have tried the following:

`tapply(quantile(CLEARPOND$word_frequency, probs = c(.05, .10, .15, .20, .25,.30,.35,.40,.45,.50,.55,.60,.65,.70,.75,.80,.85,.90,.95)), CLEARPOND$Colthearts_N, mean)`

which returns the following error:

`Error in tapply(quantile(CLEARPOND$word_frequency, probs = c(0.5, 0.1,  : arguments must have same length`

Is there anyway to fix this/ do this in a more logical way?

I basically want to divide the variable *word_frequency* into bins of 5% increments. And then find the mean of *Colthearts_N* for each of those bins. I would also ideally like to plot this on a scatter plot.

My percentiles for *word_frequency* are as follows:

> 5% 10% 15% 20% 25% 30% 35% 40% 45% 50% 55% 60% 65% 70% 75% 80% 85%
> 90% 95% 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2  3   4   6  11

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `quantile` output length will be the length of the `probs` which may not match with the column length of Colthearts_N.  You may need is `cut` and the breaks as `quantile` and this should go as grouping variable.  Without a reproducible example, it is not clear though i.e. `grp <- cut(CLEARPOND$word_frequency, breaks = quantile(CLEARPOND$word_frequency, probs = seq(.05, .95, by = .05))); tapply(CLEARPOND$Colthearts_N, grp, mean)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you Akrun, I tried replicating this and I got the error: ```Error in cut.default(CLEARPOND$word_frequency, breaks = quantile(CLEARPOND$word_frequency,  : 
  'breaks' are not unique```

Comment: I've added more information which hopefully makes it clearer

Answer (score 1):

I invented data to test the solution; I believe it achieves your goal

```
set.seed(42)
CLEARPOND <- data.frame(
  word_frequency = rnorm(1000),
  Colthearts_N = sample(1:100,
    size = 1000, replace = TRUE
  )
) %>% arrange(
  word_frequency
)

mutate(CLEARPOND,
  bin = cut(
    x = word_frequency,
    breaks = c(
      -Inf, quantile(word_frequency,
        probs = seq(from = 0.05, to = .95, by = .05)
      ),
      Inf
    )
  )
) |>
  group_by(bin) |>
  summarise(avg = mean(Colthearts_N),
            n= n())
```

Comment: Thank you Nir, I have attempted to replicate this but my R proficiency is limited, I ran: ```mutate(CLEARPOND,
       bin = cut(
         x = CLEARPOND$word_frequency,
         breaks = c(
           -Inf, quantile(CLEARPOND$word_frequency,
                          probs = seq(from = 0.05, to = .95, by = .05)
           ),
           Inf
         )
       )
) |>
  group_by(bin) |>
  summarise(avg = mean(CLEARPOND$Colthearts_N),
            n= n())``` and I got the following errors (see next comment)

Comment: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `bin = cut(...)`.
Caused by error in `cut.default()`:
! 'breaks' are not unique
Backtrace:
 1. dplyr::mutate(...)
 7. base::cut.default(...)
 8. base::stop("'breaks' are not unique")

Comment: I have added more information which hopefully makes it clearer

Comment: when you are in a mutate, you automatically have access to the variables of the dataset being mutated, it is a bad codesmell to use `$` and repeat the name of the data under mutation whenever you reference its variables in your code. I don't understand what you wished to alter in the mutate, I wouldnt think you would need to unless my guess on the properties of CLEARPOND was wrong in some relevant way.